# Difference between MustInherit and Abstract Class

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, class, abstract-class

Could someone please explain to me the differences between an abstract class and a class marked MustInherit?

Both can implement shared and instance constructors and logic. Both can/must be inherited.

So why use one over the other and what is the difference?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`MustInherit` is to `VB.NET` as `abstract` is to `C#`

Comment: Also, if you need more info check the link for the MSDN documentation in CRice's post.

Answer (score 7):

`MustInherit` is VB.NET and `abstract` is c# - they are modifiers that declare the same thing.

[abstract (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)

[MustInherit (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/mustinherit)