# How to define a must inherit class

Tags: c#, oop

How to define a must inherit class? in C#

Comment: Coming from VB.Net? Good luck! Also covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189405/difference-between-mustinherit-and-abstract-class

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You mark the class as [`abstract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx) (this is the C# analogue to the VB.NET `Must Inherit`).

This will ensure it can't be instantiated directly.

From the linked MSDN article:

> The abstract modifier indicates that the thing being modified has a missing or incomplete implementation. The abstract modifier can be used with classes, methods, properties, indexers, and events. **Use the abstract modifier in a class declaration to indicate that a class is intended only to be a base class of other classes**. Members marked as abstract, or included in an abstract class, must be implemented by classes that derive from the abstract class.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: but when you define a class as abstract does it mean that it must be inherited?

Comment: @thechmodmaster - Well, you can't create an instance of such a class directly. You can only create instances of classes that inherit from it. If that matches your concept of "must be inherited", I don't know. It does match mine.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `abstract` modifier.

```
public abstract class MyClass()
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can define a class as `abstract`, or give it a protected-only constructor. `abstract` is better.

Answer (score 5):

If u want to create a class, that has to be inherited, you'll need to mark it with the `abstract` modifier.

```
public abstract MyClass
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible enforse needness of derivation or implementation in code, if *that* was a question.

But:

You can define an `interface` to force consumer to *implement* it.

Or you can define `abstract class` with only abstract members to force consumer to override **all** of them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, thats what I ment: how to define a class in a way that would require to inherit it. you want to Ensure that this class would be inherit.

Answer (score 0):

An interface would be best.

If you need to simulate the functionality , and its not a requirement that it fail at compile time...

1. define a method in the base class.  Throw a an exception as the only line in the implementation. You might want to make the message very very clear about what the problem is.
2. override the method in the super class(es) and implement them.
   If you fail to implement in a super class, you will get the exception.

Not perfect, but say you are trying to port code from vb.net... this could work.